# How to Download Matlab Compiler

Tags: matlab

I want to download matlab compiler for my `MatLab r2013a`, but each time I click on the link it always send me to this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/index.html?s_cid=BB) and when I clicked on Get trial software and also typed in my email and lastly signed in, it will tell me, check the picture [here](http://bhekor.blogspot.com/), sorry I can't post the picture. Please Where can I get it from, I don't mind paid version (Paid Product and not free product trial). Thanks

Comment: You see where it says "need additional help - contact sales?" on the right hand side? I suggest you contact sales

Comment: Who distributes Matlab in your country? Who manages your current license? You should probably speak to them about this...

Answer (score 2):

You can't download a non-trial version of MATLAB Compiler. You can download a trial version (as you've discovered), but to get a non-trial version you will need to contact your MathWorks account manager.

You can do either via the "Contact Sales" link on the website, or by phone.

Comment: But I can't download the the trial version also for  some reason. Please check the message here:  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Khe8p6vpCRU/VXlgXbCNTwI/AAAAAAAAAM0/VtL116xbz2g/s1600/cde.png

Comment: Looks like you need to contact MathWorks even for the trial version.